# bootstrap push and pull change page layout got extra space

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use a button which will trigger a event to change variable `display` 
and then to change layout

if `display == "v1"`  the page layout should be

```
----------------------------
|  A                       |
----------------------------
|  B                       |
----------------------------
|  C                       |
----------------------------
```

code(this is what I want)

```
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <img src="https://api.fnkr.net/testimg/900x100/F00/FFF/?text=A" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <img src="https://api.fnkr.net/testimg/900x600/E82/FFF/?text=B" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <img src="https://api.fnkr.net/testimg/900x200/F56/FFF/?text=C" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
```

if the  `display == "v2"`  the page layout should be

```
----------------------------
|        |  A              |
|   B    |------------------
|        |  C              |
----------------------------
```

code(still has problem)

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
        <img src="https://api.fnkr.net/testimg/900x100/F00/FFF/?text=A" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 ">
        <img src="https://api.fnkr.net/testimg/900x600/E82/FFF/?text=B" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
        <img src="https://api.fnkr.net/testimg/900x200/F56/FFF/?text=C" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
```

But my code [here](https://jsbin.com/rosakexubo/edit?html,output) have problem , there is extra space between A and C

```
----------------------------
|        |  A              |
|   B    |------------------
|        |                 |
----------------------------
|         |  C             |
----------------------------
```

how can I fix this ??

and I use reactjs, so I want the logic like : 
    `<div className={display==="v1" ? "col-xs-12" : "col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6" }>`

Ii means I won't write like this:

```
{ if(display==="v1"){
    return (
            <div class="col-xs-12">
            <img src="https://api.fnkr.net/testimg/900x100/F00/FFF/?text=A" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <img src="https://api.fnkr.net/testimg/900x600/E82/FFF/?text=B" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <img src="https://api.fnkr.net/testimg/900x200/F56/FFF/?text=C" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
    )else{
        return (
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
                <img src="https://api.fnkr.net/testimg/900x100/F00/FFF/?text=A" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 ">
                    <img src="https://api.fnkr.net/testimg/900x600/E82/FFF/?text=B" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
                    <img src="https://api.fnkr.net/testimg/900x200/F56/FFF/?text=C" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
        )
    }
} }
```

How can I fix the layout `display == "v2"` ??

Answer (score 0):

For that you need move A and C div or image in one div ( col-sm-6 ). Like this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
  <img src="https://api.fnkr.net/testimg/900x100/F00/FFF/?text=A" class="img-responsive">
  <br/>
  <img src="https://api.fnkr.net/testimg/900x200/F56/FFF/?text=C" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 ">
  <img src="https://api.fnkr.net/testimg/900x600/E82/FFF/?text=B" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

Here is demo: https://jsfiddle.net/54ebzzzr/1/

Comment: thanks, this can fix `display==v2`, but the `display==v1`  's layout is destroyed, it should be A ,B ,C